# How does delegate call differ from normal method call ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, delegates, protocols

Whenever I wanted to inform something to parent class, I have used delegate instead of calling directly parent's functions. I have implemented like this...

eg:

```
    CustomClass *custom = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
    // assign delegate
    custom.delegate = self; // Here we are giving parent instance like normal method call.
    [custom helloDelegate];
```

In custom class, I have intimated parent like below....

```
-(void)helloDelegate
{
    // send message the message to the delegate
    [_delegate sayHello:self];
}
```

So my doubts , how does it differ from direct call?. Setting delegate variable with self is somewhat equal to giving the parent instance to child and let the child call the function whenever required, how does protocols help here or why do we need protocols? what is the advantage?

thanx

Comment: It promotes loose coupling

Comment: It's the same if you never change your delegate, it's different if your delegate could be more than one thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "inform something to parent class" ? If you're in the derived class, then the derived class itself is an version of parent class. Though if you want to inform something to parent class, use [super methodName:].

Comment: @zneak Can you give little more info about it?

Comment: @CodenameLambda1 its not derived.. custom class is loaded from parent...

Comment: @Newbee : Please share your custom class loading code here in your question.

Comment: @CodenameLambda1 Its just sample code I wrote for my understanding.. In real code I have pushed viewcontroller from other (with UINavigationController). To communicate from pushed to pushing... I have used delegate... I just wanted to know Is it really required?

Comment: @Newbee, in theory, any object that has the correct method can be used as a delegate. That's useful because you can want delegates that do different things. You simply seem to not be exploring that possibility by always having a delegate that does the same one thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working example of the advantage of using a delegate as opposed to using a direct relation.

Say you are writing a universal app. You have two view controllers in your code `iPadViewController` and `iPhoneViewController` and they both need to get data from a web service. So you create a class for you web service call `webServiceDownloaderClass`.

Now, both your view controllers need to be notified when the `webServiceDownloaderClass` has finished.

Your options here...

**Option 1 strong coupling**

In you `iPadViewController` you define a method `- (void)webServiceDidGetArray:(NSArray *)array;`. And in the `iPhoneViewController` you define the same method.

In order for the `webServiceDownloaderClass` to call these methods it now needs a reference to each of the controllers...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IPadViewController *iPadController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IPhoneViewController *iPhoneController;
```

and then when it finishes it needs to determine which one to call...

```
if (iPadController) {
    [iPadController webServiceDidGetArray];
}

etc....
```

The cons here are that the view controllers are sort of defining what the web service class does when it is finished. Also, if you add another controller you have another property and no actual guarantee that the controller you referenced actually has the method you are trying to call.

**Option 2 delegation**

In your we service class you define a protocol.

```
@protocol WebServiceDownloaderDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)webServiceDidGetArray:(NSArray *)array

@end
```

and a delegate...

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <WebServiceDownloaderDelegate> delegate;
```

Now you are defining the actions of the web service class in the web service class. And you only need one reference to any class wants to be the delegate. Also, any class can be the delegate. So now both the iPad and iPhone controller can be the delegate and by conforming the the protocol they are "promising" the web service class that they will implement the required method `- (void)webServiceDidGetArray:(NSArray *)array;`.

Of course, this is just one case where delegates can be useful.

There are also cases for when you should possibly use a direct relationship rather than delegation.

Answer (score 2):

your question is really about the difference between subclassing rather than implementing protocols (or interfaces in other languages like java)..

with delegates, you are implementing a protocol.. (which is a contract between the class referencing the delegate and the delegate itself).. this gives you more flexibility than subclassing because with subclassing you are automatically inheriting all the methods in the superclass (which is far more restricting than simply using some of the methods of another class.. in other words: subclassing = **is a** relationship.. whereas as implementing a protocol (same as delegation) = **has a** relationship.

if you read any book about design patterns.. they will talk extensively about the advantages of loose coupling your code and writing code that *prevents modification but allows extension* etc etc.. basically using delegation rather than subclassing is one way of fulfilling those design best practices.

Answer (score 0):

A delegate call *is not* different from an ordinary method call!

What is different is how things are used, and this has nothing to do with the call mechanism.  Delegates are used to decouple the definition of the code providing the delegate service from the code "consuming" the delegate service, so that the "consumer" (which, oddly, is usually a service on behalf of the delegate provider) does not have to be coded to know about THAT SPECIFIC delegate provider.

In Objective C delegates are commonly implemented using "protocols", but this is far from the only use of protocols.  Objective C uses them extensively in providing common interfaces among the various Cocoa classes.

And, in limited circumstances, one can legitimately implement a delegate using a common superclass rather than a protocol.

If you have two classes that are part of the same development effort and which would not be likely to ever be used apart from each other, there is no need to employ the delegate "pattern" to facilitate communication between them, even though they are is a service-consumer/service-provider relationship.  The only reason to do so would be "on spec", in case the "service" were ever reused unchanged in a different project.